# how to drag an drop a CSV file into a c# GUI and display the contents in a... e.g listbox?

Tags: c#, csv, drag-and-drop, listbox, windows-forms-designer

I found this code for dragging and dropping files into a GUI but it just seems to display the filepath. the csv file contains Hex Values, how do I display and use these?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(Form_DragEnter);
        this.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(Form_DragDrop);

                void Form_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                    else
                        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None; 

                }
                void Form_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
                {
                    string[] FileList = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);

                    foreach (string File in FileList)
                        this.Listbox1.Items.Add(File); 
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the file opening and parsing code yourself. The clipboard data for a file drop is simply the filename itself, not the contents of a file.

If you think about this logically, you will realise why (i.e. think of what dragging and then dropping a file would entail each time you did it).

Comment: Ye that makes sense, I'm new to programming. does it take much code to achieve this?

Comment: Is it even possible using Drag and drop? or do you have to manually add the file in the solution explorer?

Comment: It is possible, you just need to use the filename as a parameter to a method that does it. I'd suggest reading up about StreamReader and how to split strings.